# How can i write this function that mostly prints to a file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I posted about another part of this code yesterday but I've run into another problem. I made a character generator for an RPG and im trying to get the program the output of a character sheet function to a .txt file, but i think whats happening is that the function may return a `None`value for some of the stats (which is totally normal,) and then i get an error because of that when i try to write to a .txt file. I'm totally stumped, and help would be vastly appreciated!

```
# Character Sheet Function.
def char_shee():
    print "Name:", name
    print "Class:", character_class
    print "Class Powers:", class_power
    print "Alignment:", alignment
    print "Power:", pow, pow_mod()
    print "Intelligence:", iq, iq_mod()
    print "Agility:", agi, agi_mod()
    print "Constitution:", con, con_mod()
    print "Cynicism:", cyn, cyn_mod()
    print "Charisma:", cha, cha_mod()
    print "All Characters Start With 3 Hit Dice"
    print"""
\t\t{0}'s History
\t\t------------------
\t\tAge:{1}
\t\t{2}
\t\t{3}
\t\t{4}
\t\t{5}
\t\t{6}
\t\t{7}
\t\t{8}
\t\t{9}
\t\tGeneral Disposition: {10}
\t\tMost important thing is: {11}
\t\tWho is to blame for worlds problems: {12}
\t\tHow to solve the worlds problems: {13}
""".format(name, age, gender_id, ethnic_pr, fcd, wg, fogo_fuck, cur_fam,fam_fuk, nat_nur, gen_dis, wha_wor, who_pro, how_pro)

char_shee()
print "Press enter to continue"
raw_input()

# Export to text file? 
print """Just because I like you, let me know if you want this character
saved to a text file. Please remember if you save your character not to 
name it after something important, or you might lose it. 
"""
text_file = raw_input("Please type 'y' or 'n', if you want a .txt file")
if text_file == "y":
    filename = raw_input("\nWhat are we calling your file, include .txt")
    target = open(filename, 'w')
    target.write(char_shee()
    target.close
    print "\nOk I created your file."
    print """
Thanks so much for using the Cyberpanky N.O.W Character Generator
By Ray Weiss
Goodbye
"""
else:
    print """
Thanks so much for using the Cyberpanky N.O.W Character Generator
By Ray Weiss
Goodbye
"""
```

EDIT: Here is the output i get:

```
> Please type 'y' or 'n', if you want a .txt filey
> 
> What are we calling your file, include .txt123.txt <function char_shee
> at 0x2ba470> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "cncg.py", line
> 595, in <module>
>     target.write(pprint(char_shee)) TypeError: must be string or read-only character buffer, not None
```

Comment: Please show the actual error traceback.

Comment: Also note that `target.close` does nothing.  `target.close()` does something.

Comment: Just an advice: if you have more than a couple items to format, use the `"...{blah}{foo}{bar}...".format(blah=...,foo=...,bar=...)` syntax, you'll thank yourself later.

Comment: an till we're at it: close the parenthesis of your `target.write` in your code..

Answer (score 3):

Using `print` writes to `sys.stdout`, it doesn't *return* a value.

You you want `char_shee` to return the character sheet string to write it to a file, you'll need to just build that string instead.

To ease building the string, use a list to collect your strings:

```
def char_shee():
    sheet = []
    sheet.append("Name: " + name)
    sheet.append("Class: " + character_class)
    # ... more appends ...

    # Return the string with newlines
    return '\n'.join(sheet)
```

Comment: using return instead of print? I think i can do that, thanks!

Comment: Im putting it together now, ill update as to how it goes, thanks!

Comment: @lerugray: Post a new question if you have a new problem. Don't change the premise of this question.

Comment: you got it, i think i figured it out anyway :) thanks again everyone

Comment: nevermind, ill post a new question, still not working, new error.

Comment: follow up question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583595/whats-wrong-with-my-function-that-im-trying-to-write-to-a-txt-file

Answer (score 1):

you forgot parenthesis here:

```
target.write(char_shee())
target.close()
```

and as @Martijn Pieters pointed out you should return value from `char_shee()`, instead of printing them.

Comment: Won't help, since `char_shee()` doesn't actually return anything, it just prints.

Comment: @Woobie -- Well, it will *help* to get rid of the SyntaxError.  It fixes one of the at least 2 problems in this code ... Martijn's answer addresses the other one.