# whats wrong with my function that im trying to write to a txt.file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im a newbie and im stumped. I asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582907/how-can-i-write-this-function-that-mostly-prints-to-a-file) and i tried the solution and im hitting another error. In this question ill include my whole code to be as specific as possible. I would love to just get this `character_sheet()` function to print to a .txt file. Thanks in advance!

```
##########################################################
# Cyberpanky N.O.W Python Character Generator by Ray Weiss
#
# Created 9/24/2012
#
# Much thanks to Connor Daliposon 
# Mho made a very readable D&D Character Generator  
# That a Python newbie like me could understand                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
##########################################################

# Imports
import random
from pprint import pprint


# Hey there
print """
Hello world & welcome to the CYBERPANKY N.O.W. character generator.
Programmed by Ray Weiss. 
To quit at anytime, press CNTRL-C.
"""

print "Lets figure out your stats first. Press enter to continue."
raw_input()

# Stat Roller
# Rolls 3D6 and adds the sum together and prints

def roll_stats():
    a = random.randint(1, 6)
    b = random.randint(1, 6) 
    c = random.randint(1, 6)
    d = random.randint(1, 6)
    list = [a, b, c, d]
    list.sort()
    add = sum(list[1:4])
    return add

# Modifiers

def pow_mod():
    a = "|+1 to hit on mele attack rolls| "
    b = "|+1 damage on mele attack rolls|"

    if pow >= 15 and pow < 17:
        return a
    if pow >= 17:
        return a + b
    else: 
        return " ~no modifiers~"

def iq_mod():   
    a = "|-500$ to invest in cyberspace| "
    b = "|Reroll Street Doc abilities|"

    if iq >= 15 and iq < 17:
        return a
    if iq >= 17:
        return a + b
    else: 
        return " ~no modifiers~"

def agi_mod():
    a = "|+1 to hit with ranged weapons| "
    b = "|-1 to hit with ranged weapons|"

    if agi >= 12:
        return a
    if agi <= 9:
        return b
    else: 
        return " ~no modifiers~"

def con_mod():
    a = "|+1 hit point per hit dice|"
    b = "|-1 hit point per hit dice|"

    if con >= 15:
        return a
    elif con <= 6: 
        return b
    else: 
        return " ~no modifiers~"

def cyn_mod():
    a = "|Add 10% to earned experience|"
    b = "|Add 5% to earned experience|"
    c = "|Subtract 10% from earned experience|"
    d = "|Subtract 20% from earned experience|"

    if cyn >= 15:
        return a
    elif cyn > 12 and cyn < 15:
        return b
    elif cyn > 6 and cyn < 9:
        return c
    elif cyn <= 6:
        return d
    else: 
        return " ~no modifiers~"

def cha_mod():
    a = "|+1 to reaction rolls|"
    b = "|-1 to reaction rolls|"

    if cha >= 15:
        return a 
    if cha <= 8:
        return b
    else: 
        return " ~no modifiers~"

# Prints stats + modifiers.
pow = roll_stats()
print "Power:", pow, pow_mod()
iq = roll_stats()
print "Intelligence:", iq, iq_mod()
agi = roll_stats()
print "Agility:", agi, agi_mod()
con = roll_stats()
print "Constitution:", con, con_mod()
cyn = roll_stats()
print "Cynicism:", cyn, cyn_mod()
cha = roll_stats()
print "Charisma:", cha, cha_mod()

print "\nIf you dont like your stats, tough shit. This is Cyberpanky N.O.W."
print "\nPress enter to continue."
raw_input()

# Choose Class

print """In Cyberpanky N.O.W. there are only 3 character classes. 

1. Samurai: Badass mercenaries. Can make multiple attacks.  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. Street Docs: Hackers / Doctors. Can heal & hack. 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3. Shaman: Magical prophets that follow spirit animals and cast miracles 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
type = int(raw_input("Please type a 1, 2, or 3 > "))

if type == 1:
    character_class = "Samurai"
    class_power = """* Attack multiple times for a -2 to hit penalty.
* Uses a D10 for Physical hit box.
* Has a + 1 to hit bonus that levels up to level 5. 
"""
    name = raw_input("Alright {}, tell me your name >".format(character_class))

elif type == 2:
    character_class = "Street Doc"
    class_power = """* Roll IQ to mess with electronics
* Can heal party members after combat for 1D4 Hit Points
* Can perform cyberwear installation or surgery with proper tools.
"""
    name = raw_input("Alright {}, tell me your name >".format(character_class))

elif type == 3:
    character_class = "Shaman"
    class_power = """* Can cast Miracles.
* Can call for a saving grace if they are on their last Cool Hit Box
* Can do favors for their god for more miracles, or pay a tithe.
"""
    name = raw_input("Alright {}, tell me your name >".format(character_class))

# Alignment

print"""\nAlright {}, pick an alignment, it's not that important;

1. Narcissist: Cocky bastard, you think you are the best.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. Neutral: Pretty self explanatory dipshit. 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3. Nihilist: You care about nothing Lebowski, You'll cut off their Johnson. 
""".format(name)

x = int(raw_input("Please type a 1, 2, or 3 > "))

if x == 1:
    alignment = "Narcissist"

elif x == 2:
    alignment = "Neutral"

elif x == 3:
    alignment = "Nihilist"

print "\nOk you chose {} for an alignment, press enter to continue.".format(
                                                                alignment)
raw_input()

# Functions for ID generation

def gen_id():
    global gender_id
    one = "1. Straight male"
    two = "2. Gay male"
    three = "3. Transgender male pre-op"
    four = "4. Transgender male post-op"
    five = "5. Bisexual male"
    six = "6. Straight female"
    seven = "7. Gay female"
    eight = "8. Transgender female pre-op"
    nine = "9. Transgender female post-op"
    ten = "10. Bisexual female"
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    print "\nPlease hit enter to roll 1D10"
    raw_input()
    gender_id = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(gender_id)
    raw_input()

# Ethnic Profile
def eth_pr():
    global ethnic_pr
    one = "1. Native American"
    two = "2. West European"
    three = "3. East European"
    four = "4. North Asian"
    five = "5. South Asian"
    six = "6. Pacific"
    seven = "7. North African"
    eight = "8. South African"
    nine = "9. Slavic / Caucuses"
    ten = "10. Hispanic"
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    print "\nPlease hit enter to roll 1D10"
    raw_input()
    ethnic_pr = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(ethnic_pr)
    raw_input()

# Family Class Distinction
def fam_cls():
    global fcd
    one = "1. Homeless"
    two = "2. Impoverished"
    three = "3. Lower Class"
    four = "4. Lower Middle Class"
    five = "5. Middle Class"
    six = "6. Comfortable"
    seven = "7. Upper Middle Class"
    eight = "8. Upper Class"
    nine = "9. Job Creators"
    ten = "10. Warren Buffett"
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    print "Please hit enter to roll 1D10"
    raw_input()
    fcd = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(fcd)
    raw_input()

# Whats Good With Your Folks
def wha_goo():
    global wg, one_x, two_x
    one_x = "1. Things Are Good With Your Folks; Go to Current Family Affairs"
    two_x = "2. Your folks are fucked; go to Your Folks Got Fucked"
    list = [one_x, two_x]
    pprint(list)
    print "Please hit enter to roll 1D2"
    raw_input()
    wg = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(wg)
    raw_input()

# Your Folks Got Fucked
def yo_fo():
    global fogo_fuck
    one = "1. Your parents were mugged and murdered, just like Batman"
    two = "2. Your parents were both convicted of murder"
    three = "3. Parents decapitated by a truck"
    four = "4. Parents addicted to coke, put you in an orphanage"
    five = "5. Parents were corporate spies and assinated in front of you"
    six = "6. Parents abandonded you at a young age and joined a cult"
    seven = "7. Your parents died from STDs contracted from aldultery"
    eight = "8. Parents owed mob a bunch of money, sleeping with fishies"
    nine = "9. Nuclear explosion incinerated parents, their shadow remains"
    ten = "10. Parents shot themselves immediately after you were born."
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    print "Please hit enter to roll 1D10"
    raw_input()
    fogo_fuck = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(fogo_fuck)
    raw_input()

# Current Family Affairs
def cu_fa():
    global cur_fam, one_y, two_y
    one_y = "1. Things are ok with family, go to Nature Or Nurture"
    two_y = "2. Your family is fucked, go to Your Family Is Fucked"
    list = [one_y, two_y]
    pprint(list)
    print "Please hit enter to roll 1D2"
    raw_input()
    cur_fam = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(cur_fam)
    raw_input()

# Your Family Got Fucked
def fa_fu():
    global fam_fuk
    one = "1. Market tanked with president Paul, dead broke family."
    two = "2. Home invaders raped and murded the women in your family"
    three = "3. Racial Supremisicist drove your family from their home"
    four = "4. Whole family was abducted by aliens, never seen again"
    five = "5. Radiation leak hospitalized your whole family."
    six = "6. Family was accidentally napalmed by the UN, all dead."
    seven = "7. Family came down with malaria"
    eight = "8. Family has some obvious dealings with Illuminati"
    nine = "9. Family eaten alive by cannibals"
    ten = "10. Make it up dipshit"
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    raw_input()
    fam_fuk = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(fam_fuk)
    raw_input()

# Nature Or Nurture
def na_nu():
    global nat_nur
    one = "1. Your childhood was very boring & average" 
    two = "2. Your childhood was spent moving from city to city"
    three = "3. Your childhood was depraved; hungry and lonely"
    four = "4. Your childhood was rewarding, social & fun."
    five = "5. You were a sick child, spent a lot of time in bed"
    six = "6. You were sent to a preppy boarding school as a kid"
    seven = "7. You got addicted to drugs; it screwed you up."
    eight = "8. You killed another kid, spent time in a hospital"
    nine = "9. You were a child genius, but had few friends"
    ten = "10. Make it up dipshit"
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    print "Please hit enter to roll 1D10"
    raw_input()
    nat_nur = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(nat_nur)
    raw_input()

# General Disposition
def ge_di():
    global gen_dis
    one = "1. Friendly"
    two = "2. Unfriendly"
    three = "3. Shy"
    four = "4. Outgoing"
    five = "5. Unpretentious"
    six = "6. Pretentious"
    seven = "7. Hyperactive"
    eight = "8. Depressed"
    nine = "9. Wonderful Human Being"
    ten = "10. Scumbag"
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    print "Please hit enter to roll 1D10"
    raw_input()
    gen_dis = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(gen_dis)
    raw_input()

# Whats the most important thing in the world
def wh_wo():
    global wha_wor
    one = "1. Money"
    two = "2. Kicking ass"
    three = "3. Getting fucked up"
    four = "4. Family & friends"
    five = "5. Business"
    six = "6. The internet" 
    seven = "7. Faith"
    eight = "8. Style"
    nine = "9. Anarchy"
    ten = "10. Selfishness"
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    print "Please hit enter to roll 1D10"
    raw_input()
    wha_wor = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(wha_wor)
    raw_input()

# Who is to blame for the worlds problems?
def wh_pr():
    global who_pro
    one = "1. Corporations"
    two = "2. Leftists"
    three = "3. Fate"
    four = "4. Religion"
    five = "5. The Illuminatus"
    six = "6. The News Media"
    seven = "7. The UN"
    eight = "8. Your Neighbors"
    nine = "9. Aliens"
    ten = "10. President Ron Paul"
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    print "Please hit enter to roll 1D10"
    raw_input()
    who_pro = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(who_pro)
    raw_input()

# How do you solve the worlds problems
def ho_pr():
    global how_pro
    one = "1. Kill them all"
    two = "2. But them out"
    three = "3. Intimidation"
    four = "4. Diplomacy"
    five = "5. Free trade"
    six = "6. Seduction"
    seven = "7. New-Age spirituality"
    eight = "8. Religious fanaticism"
    nine = "9. Federal power"
    ten = "10. Who gives a shit"
    list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten]
    pprint(list)
    print "Please hit enter to roll 1D10"
    raw_input()
    how_pro = random.choice(list)
    print "You rolled {}, press enter to continue.".format(how_pro)
    raw_input()


# ID Generation

print ("Alright {}, now we need to figure out your personality & life story."
                                                               .format(name))
print "\n\t\t1. Ethnics, Genes, & Looks"
print "\nTo figure out your age, we add 15 to 1D10.\n"
age = random.randint(1, 10) + 15
print "Press enter to continue dipshit."
raw_input()
print "Age:", age
print "\t\tGender Identity\n"
gen_id()
print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
print "\t\tEthnic Profile\n"
eth_pr()
print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
print "\t\t2. Ballz Of Our Fathers"
print "\n"
print "\t\tFamily Class Distinction"
fam_cls()
print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
print "\t\tWhat's Good With Your Folks"
wha_goo()
print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
if wg == one_x:
    fogo_fuck = "none"
    print "\t\tCurrent Family Affairs"
    cu_fa()
    print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
    if cur_fam == one_y:
        fam_fuk = "none"
        print "\t\tNature Or Nurture?"
        na_nu()
        print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
    if cur_fam == two_y:
        print "\t\t Your Family Is Fucked"
        fa_fu()
        print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
        print "\t\tNature Or Nurture?"
        na_nu()
        print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
if wg == two_x:
    print "\t\tYour Folks Got Fucked"
    yo_fo()
    print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
    print "\t\tCurrent Family Affairs"
    cu_fa()
    print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
    fam_fuck = "none"
    print "\t\tNature Or Nurture?"
    na_nu()
    print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
    if cur_fam == one_y:
        fam_fuck = "none"
        print "\t\tNature Or Nurture?"
        na_nu()
        print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
    if cur_fam == two_y:
        print "\t\t Your Family Is Fucked"
        fa_fu()
        print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
print "\t\t3. What Makes you tick"
print "\n"
print "\t\tGeneral Disposition"
ge_di()
print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
print "\t\tWhat's The Most Important Thing In The World?"
wh_wo()
print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
print "\t\tWho Is To Blame For The World's Problems?"
wh_pr()
print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
print "\t\tHow Do You Solve Your / The Worlds Problem"
ho_pr()
print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""

#Starting Money
gold = roll_stats() * 100

print "Ok so lets sum that up, please hit enter to continue"
raw_input()

print"""
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""

# Print Character Sheet Function.
def char_shee():
    print "Name:", name
    print "Class:", character_class
    print "Class Powers:", class_power
    print "Alignment:", alignment
    print "Power:", pow, pow_mod()
    print "Intelligence:", iq, iq_mod()
    print "Agility:", agi, agi_mod()
    print "Constitution:", con, con_mod()
    print "Cynicism:", cyn, cyn_mod()
    print "Charisma:", cha, cha_mod()
    print "Money:", gold
    print "All Characters Start With 3 Hit Dice"
    print"""
\t\t{0}'s History
\t\t------------------
\t\tAge:{1}
\t\t{2}
\t\t{3}
\t\t{4}
\t\t{5}
\t\t{6}
\t\t{7}
\t\t{8}
\t\t{9}
\t\tGeneral Disposition: {10}
\t\tMost important thing is: {11}
\t\tWho is to blame for worlds problems: {12}
\t\tHow to solve the worlds problems: {13}
""".format(name, age, gender_id, ethnic_pr, fcd, wg, fogo_fuck, cur_fam,fam_fuk, nat_nur, gen_dis, wha_wor, who_pro, how_pro)

char_shee()
print "Press enter to continue"
raw_input()

# Export to text file? 

#character sheet function for writing
def character_sheet():
    sheet = []
    sheet.append("Name: " + name)
    sheet.append("Class: " + character_class)
    sheet.append("Class Powers :" + class_power)
    sheet.append("Alignment: " + alignment)
    sheet.append("Power: ", pow, pow_mod())
    sheet.append("Intelligence: ", iq, iq_mod())
    sheet.append("Agility: ", agi, agi_mod())
    sheet.append("Constitution: ", con, con_mod())
    sheet.append("Cynicism", cyn, cyn_mod())
    sheet.append("Charisma: ", cha, cha_mod())
    sheet.append("Money: " + gold)
    sheet.append("All Characters Start With 3 Hit Dice")
    sheet.append("""
\t\t{0}'s History
\t\t------------------
\t\tAge:{1}
\t\t{2}
\t\t{3}
\t\t{4}
\t\t{5}
\t\t{6}
\t\t{7}
\t\t{8}
\t\t{9}
\t\tGeneral Disposition: {10}
\t\tMost important thing is: {11}
\t\tWho is to blame for worlds problems: {12}
\t\tHow to solve the worlds problems: {13}
""".format(name, age, gender_id, ethnic_pr, fcd, wg, fogo_fuck, cur_fam,fam_fuk, nat_nur, gen_dis, wha_wor, who_pro, how_pro))

    # Return the string with newlines
    return '\n'.join(sheet)


print """Just because I like you, let me know if you want this character
saved to a text file. Please remember if you save your character not to 
name it after something important, or you might lose it. 
"""
text_file = raw_input("Please type 'y' or 'n', if you want a .txt file > ")
if text_file == "y":
    filename = raw_input("\nWhat are we calling your file, include .txt > ")
    target = open(filename, 'w')
    target.write(character_sheet())
    target.close()
    print "\nOk I created your file."
    print """
Thanks so much for using the Cyberpanky N.O.W Character Generator
By Ray Weiss
Goodbye
"""
else:
    print """
Thanks so much for using the Cyberpanky N.O.W Character Generator
By Ray Weiss
Goodbye
"""
```

And here is the error output

```
> File "cncg.py", line 634, in <module>
>     target.write(character_sheet())   File "cncg.py", line 596, in character_sheet
>     sheet.append("Power: ", pow, pow_mod()) TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (3 given) Raymond-Weisss-MacBook-Pro:mystuff
> Raylug$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to turn your old `print "Power:", pow, pow_mod()` line into a string to append:

```
sheet.append("Power: " + str(pow) + ' ' + pow_mod())
```

Or use a formatter:

```
sheet.append("Power: {0} {1}".format(pow, pow_mod()))
```

because `.append()` only takes one item at a time.

Comment: I got this output trying that

File "cncg.py", line 596, in character_sheet
    sheet.append("Power: " + pow + ' ' + pow_mod())
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
Raymond-Weisss-MacBook-Pro:mystuff Raylug$

Comment: @lerugray: Right, then use the formatter version, it's easier for mixed types. Or call `str()` on the integer, `pow` in this case.

Comment: @Marijn Pieters got this error:

File "cncg.py", line 634, in <module>
    target.write(character_sheet())
  File "cncg.py", line 599, in character_sheet
    sheet.append("Constitution: {0} {1}".format(con + con_mod()))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
Raymond-Weisss-MacBook-Pro:mystuff Raylug$

Comment: Ill try turning it into a string

Comment: @lerugray Martijn didn't say `format(con + con_mod())`, he said `format(con, con_mod())`.

Comment: Use a comma, not `+`: `sheet.append("Constitution: {0} {1}".format(con, con_mod()))`

Comment: It works! Thank you everyone so much! Stack Overflow is the best! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using more than one argument in the `append` method, as the error said :

```
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
```

You have to concatenize the variables and function results in the string, as you can't concatenize strings with other types, you will have to convert everything into a string before concatenizing them.

```
sheet.append("Power: " + str(pow) + " " + str(pow_mod()))
```

Comment: This omits the space in-between `pow` and `pow_mod()` (the latter returns a string without a leading space). The original code (other qusetion) used `print "Power:", pow, pow_mod()` which inserts spaces for you.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Whoops, I've completely forgot about that. Thanks for pointing it out !